# Error message in "Copy As Graphics Expression" of graph

Tags: front-end, warning-messages, copy-as

Evaluate the following code:

```
Graph[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}}]
```

Then right-click the graph and choose `Copy As -> Graphics Expression`.

I got this error:

```
Set::write: Tag Inherited in Inherited[State] is Protected.
```

But when I press `CTRL+V` the graphics of graph is pasted correctly.

What does this error message mean? How to avoid it?

My version is 13.0.1 for Windows.

Comment: Graph is only a container of lists with a special Format as Output, thats not a Graphics object. Use GraphPlot.

Comment: That is why you have the menu `Copy As` to convert it to graphics if needed. Did you do what is written in the question?

Comment: Yes, have tried the output to convert to an image dirctly  without result.    You may click the graphics and right click Convert to Graphics in the last three entries of the list, specialized for convert, save and print.

Comment: Yes, it is basically the same and gives me exactly the same error message.

Comment: not so with vs13.3/Windows 10 for me